Azure App Insights JS script is automatically injected by Azure App Service and is blocked by Content Security Policy. How to unblock it?
We are working on an ASP.NET Core MVC application running .NET 8. It is deployed on Azure through Azure App Service. We have implemented Content Security Policy in the application and have assigned nonce values to the JS scripts that are in use.
Recently, we are getting a console error stating,
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'nonce-blabla'. Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('bla-bla'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
It is coming from a script automatically injected by azure app insights. The source of the script that is causing the csp violation is https://js.monitor.azure.com/scripts/b/ai.2.min.js
We don't have all the permissions related to the app service and we don't have any app insights related config in the codebase. We have tried adding a bunch of domains to the CSP header to get rid of the csp violation but still we are not able to solve it.
Can anyone please give any suggestion on how to resolve the CSP violation for the automatically injected script?

When you said you tried a bunch of domains in the CSP header, did you try https://js.monitor.azure.com itself?

Yes. I tried to share a sample header that we tried, but stackoverflow was marking the content as spam.


The source of the script that is causing the csp violation is https://js.monitor.azure.com/scripts/b/ai.2.min.js


We have tried adding a bunch of domains to the CSP header to get rid of the csp violation but still we are not able to solve it.

You can try to allow scripts from the trusted domain(s), such as:
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' *.azure.com" />

for more information about CSP: script-src, please check this doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src

We tried this approach as you have described to add the trusted domains in the meta tag, it still did not fix the issue.
